# example_pb2 from tensorflow.core.example works in python 2, but not python 3

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code will work with no issues in Python 2

```
from tensorflow.core.example import example_pb2
tf_example = example_pb2.Example()
tf_example.features.feature['article'].bytes_list.value.extend(['test test testing'])
```

But in Python 3, it gives this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7fc29de54f13> in <module>()
      1 from tensorflow.core.example import example_pb2
      2 tf_example = example_pb2.Example()
----> 3 tf_example.features.feature['article'].bytes_list.value.extend(['test test testing'])

TypeError: 'test test testing' has type str, but expected one of: bytes
```

Is it not supposed to work in Python 3? If so, what is the equivalent for Python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is as the error says:
`but expected one of: bytes` : You need to provide byte values instead of string values.

You just need to use `b'test test testing'`.

```
(pygpu) C:\Users\Ashutosh>python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from tensorflow.core.example import example_pb2
>>> tf_example = example_pb2.Example()
>>> tf_example.features.feature['article'].bytes_list.value.extend([b'test test testing'])
>>> tf_example
features {
  feature {
    key: "article"
    value {
      bytes_list {
        value: "test test testing"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In `Python 3.x` it happens because the bytes type in `Python 3.x` is a list of 8-bit integers. So taking one character of a string will return a one-character long string, but taking one byte of a bytes object will return an integer!